# metaclass error: type.__init__() takes 1 or 3 arguments

Tags: python, python-2.x, metaclass

I have a metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # Do something
        ...

        return super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

and a class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
```

When I use these I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type.__init__() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

What's the problem, and why does `type.__init__()` take a precisely variable number of arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that in the upgrade from python 2.5 to python 2.6 `type.__init__()` was changed so that you are no longer required to pass in `cls`. So simply make the `super` call:

```
return super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

Another solution is to avoid the `super` call altogether and do this (although it's a little less nice):

```
return type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

And everything will work fine (in python >= 2.6).

As to why `type.__init__()` can take differing numbers of arguments, check out [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/functions.html#type). It's so that as well as using it as a constructor, you can call `type(myobject)` and it will return the type of `myobject`:

```
>>> number = 1
>>> type(number)
<type 'int'>
>>> type('my string')
<type 'str'>
```

See [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/) for more information on metaclasses and type.

Comment: Note that `super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)` is the *correct* way of doing this, even in 2.5 (and as far back as 2.2.) The only case in which you pass `cls` as the first argument is with `__new__`, not with `__init__` (and that's not specific to `type` or metaclasses either.) What changed is that `type.__init__()` stopped swallowing exceptions, much like `object.__init__()`.